# Confused at to why $\prod_{g \in G}g^2=e$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $(G, \circ)$ be a finite abelian group with neutral element $e$.

$1.$ Show that in general $\prod_{g \in G}g^n\neq e$ for $n=1$

**My idea**:

I used $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, it follows that $\prod_{g \in G}g=[0]+[1]\neq[0] \in \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$

$2.$ Show that there exists an $n \in \mathbb N$ so that $\prod_{g \in G}g^n=e$

I found a solution but I do not understand it. It states

$\prod_{g \in G}g^2=\prod_{g \in G}(g\cdot g^{-1})$

I do not understand this step... Why is $g^{2}=g\cdot g^{-1}$?

Thank for your help

Comment: The group is abelian so you can rearrange the order of the products. Than in a group an element has a unique inverse (which can be also itself). Try using these two properties to show the equality that you need...

Comment: Note that the solution does not claim that for each $g\in G$, $g^2 = g\cdot g^{-1}$. It only claims that the two products are equal.

Comment: It is not true in general that $g^2=g \cdot g^{-1}$, but if you take the product of all elements twice you will have each element and its inverse.

Comment: Note that the second question can be answered easily by taking $n=|G|$ and applying Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: Or even more easily by taking $n = \prod_{g \in G} \mathrm{ord}(g)$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not true that $g^2 = g \circ g^{-1}$. Rather, each element $g$ appears in the product twice, so we let every element "appear once as itself" and "appear once as an inverse, namely its inverse's inverse". For example we can write
\begin{align}
\prod_{g \in G} g^2 &= \prod_{g \in G}g \circ (g^{-1})^{-1}\\
&= \prod_{g \in G} g \times \prod_{g \in G} (g^{-1})^{-1} \\
&= \prod_{g \in G} g \times \prod_{h \in G} h^{-1} \\
&= \prod_{g \in G} g \times \prod_{g \in G} g^{-1} \\
&= \prod_{g \in G}g \circ g^{-1}.
\end{align}

Comment: @MinaThuma, in the second final step I am reordering the product to put the two products back together (and arguably I am changing the ordering in step three or four, although that is hidden in the notation; really $\prod_{g \in G} g$ does not even make sense for non-abelian groups without fixing an ordering on $G$).